# Paralellize numpy array generation inside a class method with multiprocessing

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I'm starting to work with multiprocessing after a very long time, and I have a question regarding how can I parallelize the filling of a large numpy array from a class method, using a set of computing objects that are stored in the same class.

The simplified structure looks something like this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np

from itertools import count 
import time

class DummyCalculator:
    _ids = count(0)
    def __init__(self):
        self._id = next(self._ids)

    def compute(self, x: np.array) -> np.array
        time.sleep(10)
        return x + self._id

class DummyKeeper:
    def __init__(self):
        self._calculators = []

    def addCalculator(self, calculator: DummyCalculator) -> np.array:
        self._calculators.append(calculator)

    def myfunc(self, x: np.array) -> np.array:
        # this is what I want to be handled by multiprocessing, one process for each DummyCalculator instance
        out = np.array([c.compute(x) for c in self._calculators]).flatten()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    keeper = DummyKeeper()

    keeper.addCalculator(DummyCalculator())
    keeper.addCalculator(DummyCalculator())
    keeper.addCalculator(DummyCalculator())
    keeper.addCalculator(DummyCalculator())

    x = np.zeros(100000)

    keeper.myfunc() #-> this should trigger the processes
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

I turned out to be more simple than I expected. After a long loop of try-error I came up with this.

```
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
from pathos import multiprocessing as mp
from functools import partial
import numpy as np

from itertools import count 
import time

class DummyCalculator:
    _ids = count(0)
    def __init__(self):
        self._id = next(self._ids)

    def compute(self, x: np.array) -> np.array:
        time.sleep(10)
        return x + self._id

class DummyKeeper:
    def __init__(self):
        self._calculators = []

    def addCalculator(self, calculator: DummyCalculator) -> np.array:
        self._calculators.append(calculator)

    def dummyCalc(self, tup: tuple) -> tuple:
        i = tup[0]
        x = np.array(tup[1])
        c = self._calculators[i]
        v = c.compute(x)
        return (i, v)

    def myfunc(self, x: np.array) -> np.array:
        pool =  mp.Pool(processes = 4)
        pargs = [(i, x) for i in range(4)]
        out = pool.map(self.dummyCalc, pargs)
        # I need to preserve initial order
        out.sort(key = lambda tup: tup[0])
        out = np.array([o[1] for o in out]).flatten()
        return out


if __name__ == '__main__':

    keeper = DummyKeeper()

    c0 = DummyCalculator()
    c1 = DummyCalculator()
    c2 = DummyCalculator()
    c3 = DummyCalculator()
    keeper.addCalculator(c0)
    keeper.addCalculator(c1)
    keeper.addCalculator(c2)
    keeper.addCalculator(c3)

    x = np.zeros(100000)

    out = keeper.myfunc(x)
    print(out)
```

I just changed multiprocessing to pathos for internal reasons.